# Evaluate the following series having finite terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Evaluate the following series $$\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\frac{2^n}{1+2023^{2n}}$$

My first thoughts were that this series didn't seem to telescope so there must be some other way of solving it. I did $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\frac{2^n}{1+2023^{2n}}$$ $$\implies S=\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\frac{2^{2023-n}}{1+2023^{2(2023-n)}}$$ $$\implies S=\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\frac{2^{2023}\cdot2023^{2n}}{2^n(2023^{2n}+2023^{4046})}$$ Now when we add them or subtract both expressions nothing happens. I use this technique in integration so I thought that maybe this is useful here too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think there is a simple closed form. Numerically, $$S=0.500000488695495791471102052762975983471147\ldots$$

Comment: @Gary it's close to $0.5$ does that imply anything??

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2046265}+\frac{2}{8374396807921}+\frac{4}   {34272461793922075945}+\cdots$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found this question in a pdf designed explicitly for exam problems...I wonder why they printed this question there

Comment: what kind of answers did the exam expect (approx. values, exact fractions)?

Comment: @DS maybe approx values but all answers only in elementary functions...the one we are taught in high school or a bit above high school

Comment: was the exam held in 2023? That will tell us that there is nothing to $2023$, we should be interested in $\sum_{n=1}^a {2^n\over 1+a^{2n}}$.

Comment: @DS oh no no... consider it as a general problem... nothing special with 2023

Comment: Can we convert it in a Riemann sum? $\begin{align}S_n(x) &=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^r}{1+x^{2r}}\\&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=0}{n}\frac{2^{(\frac{r}{n})n}}{1+x^{(\frac{r}{n})n}}\end{align}$

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes you can convert...I mean idk if we can but if you're asking whether that method is suitable for me ...then yes it is

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, are you sure that the denomiantor is $1+2023^{2n}$ and not $1+2023^{2^{n}}$.

Comment: This is what the question asked....if the question is wrong, that's a whole different thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{a}\frac{2^n}{a^{2n}+1}\sim\sum_{n=0}^{p}\frac{2^n}{a^{2n}+1}+\int_{p+1}^a \frac{2^n}{a^{2n}+1}\,dn$$ Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int\frac{2^n}{a^{2n}+1}\,dn=\frac{2^n}{\log(2)}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{\log (2)}{2 \log (a)};\frac{\log (2)}{2
   \log (a)}+1;-a^{2 n}\right)$$ So, we know the integral and, for $a=2023$ and $p=3$, its numerical value is
$$3.9250182684346802140391659144\times 10^{-27}$$ and the total is
$$0.500000488695495791471102000\cdots$$
to be compared to
$$0.500000488695495791471102053\cdots$$

**Edit**

Playing with $p$ and looking for the absolute error $\Delta_p$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \log_{10}(\Delta_p) \\
 2 & -18.9329 \\
 3 & -25.2438 \\
 4 & -31.5858 \\
 5 & -37.8967 \\
 6 & -44.2077 \\
 7 & -50.5187 \\
 8 & -56.8296 \\
 9 & -63.1406 \\
 10 & -69.4515 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ that is to say
$$\Delta_p\sim 10^{-\frac{19}{3} (p+1)}$$

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of stating the obvious, the terms in the sum decrease *very* rapidly, which suggests that even a rough approximation could work reasonably well. The following combines two such rough approximations to get a passable estimate for the finite sum.

- Replace the finite sum $\,\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\,$ with the series $\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\,$.
- Approximate $\,\dfrac{1}{1+1/2023^{2n}}\,$ with $\,1-1/2023^{2n}\,$ .

The errors introduced by the two approximations happen to go in opposite directions, but the second one dominates by far, so the final estimate will be slightly below the actual value.

Step by step, let $\;a = \dfrac{1}{2023^2}\,, \,b=2a\;$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
T_{2023} = S - \frac{1}{2} = b\, \sum_{n = 0}^{2022} \,\frac{b^n}{1 + a^{n+1}} &\simeq b\, \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \,\frac{b^n}{1 + a^{n+1}}
\\ &\simeq b\, \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \,b^n \left(1 - a^{n+1}\right)
\\ &= b\left(\frac{1}{1 - b} - \frac{a}{1 - ab}\right)
\\ &= \frac{b(1-a)}{(1-b)(1-ab)}
\\ &= \frac{2a(1-a)}{(1-2a)(1-2a^2)}
\\ &= \frac{2 \cdot 2023^2\,(2023^2-1)}{(2023^2-2)(2023^4-2)}
\\ &= 0.000000\color{blue}{4886954957914}419\ldots = \widetilde{T}_{2023}
\end{align}
$$

The above approximates $\,S-\dfrac{1}{2}\,$ to $\,13\,$ significant digits, which is close to the machine precision on many architectures. It is less accurate than [Claude's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4670564/291201), but it is entirely elementary to derive.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Just to put in perspective how fast the sum converges, simply adding up the first $4$ terms gives a better approximation than my $\widetilde{T}$.

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 10^6 \cdot T_1 &      \color{blue}{0.488695}256968183495295\ldots \\
 10^6 \cdot T_2 &      \color{blue}{0.488695495791}354390216\ldots \\
 10^6 \cdot \color{red}{\widetilde{T}_{2023}} & \color{blue}{0.4886954957914}41924115\ldots \\
 10^6 \cdot T_3 &      \color{blue}{0.48869549579147110}1995\ldots \\
 10^6 \cdot T_4 &      \color{blue}{0.488695495791471102053}\ldots \\
 10^6 \cdot \color{blue}{T_{2023}} & \color{blue}{0.488695495791471102053}\ldots
\end{array}
$$